# jquery find exact string with no more or less

Tags: jquery, regex

I have some text from a breadcrumb which I am using to open menu items on a page. For example, say the `bctext = 'pasta'`.

I want to target the word "pasta", but not say "yadda yadda yadda pasta". Only an instance of the single word "pasta" should match, or if `bctext` were a phrase, then it would only find the exact phrase.

This is what I have so far:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(' + bctext + ')')
```

But this finds "yadda yadda pasta", of course.

I get the `bctext` with the following:

```
var bctext = $('#CategoryBreadcrumb ul li:last-child').prev().children().text();
```

Then, I edit the menu with the following:

```
$('ul#accordion a:contains(' + bctext + ')').parent()
                                            .addClass('special')
                                            .children('ul')
                                            .css('display','block');
```

Is what I'm going for possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('ul#accordion a').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == bctext;
}).parent().addClass('special').children('ul').css('display','block');
```

`:contains()` is not a native selector anyway so using `.filter()` with a custom callback won't have any performance drawbacks.

Comment: so sorry my jquery is not great... i am going to add more of my code above because i am not sure how to work this into what i did.

Comment: so above i added what the full code is. so now just to be clear. (and maybe i have this all wrong...) i use the filter function to find the text in the a tag and give it a variable and then compare that to the bctext i found in the breadcrumb?

Comment: ahh i didnt know you could chain onto a function like that!